# How to replace empty query with value in PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I need to replace returned query from MySQL, if it is empty, with zero, but I can't figure out how.

For example I have table named **values**. There is **device id** and some period with values.

```
id_device | 2015-05-01 | 2015-05-02 | 2015-05-03 | 2015-05-04 | 2015-05-05
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1    |    1000    |    990     |    980     |    970     |    960    |
     2    |    1150    |    1140    |    1130    |    1120    |    1100   |
     3    |    1050    |    1040    |    1030    |    1020    |    1010   |
     4    |            |            |            |            |           |
     5    |    1250    |    1240    |    1230    |    1220    |    1210   |
```

When I use

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM values");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($row) == 0) { 
         $row[1] = 0; $row[2] = 0; $row[3] = 0; $row[4] = 0; $row[5] = 0;
         }
    echo "<td>$row[1] $row[2] $row[3] $row[4] $row[5]</td>";
    }
```

The 4th row is still empty instead of being replaced by zeros. Why? And how can I replace the empty fields with zeros?

Comment: Thank's @Sarath. Sry for accidently rejected your changes. I made some grammar mistakes here, but the code still doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: (Commentary about downvotes does not belong in questions or answers. You can put them in comments if you like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that in your SQL Query, See example below:

```
SELECT `device_id`, IF(`column_name` = '', 0, `column_name`) as col_name FROM `table_name`
```

Apart from that, [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) is used to return number or rows, in executed query.

**EDIT:**

You can use [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), just incase if you are getting null values instead of blanks.

Comment: Additionally, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and will be removed in future versions, so use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your condition, the `mysql_num_rows`. It checks, how many rows your SQL query returned. It returns this number, no matter where you are in your code, until your resource object (`$sql`) is overwritten.

So what your code does is the following:

```
#execute the sql statement
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM values);
#get the rows from the sql result, on by one
#the first $row contains id_device #1 and so on
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    #here you look up the number of rows your sql statement gets
    #this always returns 5, as the result from your query does not
    #change when looking at the single lines of your result
    if (mysql_num_rows($row) == 0) { 
        #you'll never enter this condintion
        $row[1] = 0; $row[2] = 0; $row[3] = 0; $row[4] = 0; $row[5] = 0;
    }
    echo "<td>$row[1] $row[2] $row[3] $row[4] $row[5]</td>"
}
```

Try this instead:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM values);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    #checks if one of the cells is empty
    if (in_array("", $row)){
        #if so, $row will be filled with empty values
        #except for the first element, as this is your device_id
        $row = array_fill(1, count($row), 0);
    }
    echo "<td>$row[1] $row[2] $row[3] $row[4] $row[5]</td>"
}
```

Comment: I got your logic, thanks. I would give you upvote but this damn trolls has downvoted me for -3 and now my rank is too low to give upvotes :)

Comment: no problem, just wanted to point out that the problem is the php code, not the sql query. can be "fixed" by changing the sql query too though ;-)

Comment: @JEYCDEE: I've upvoted on your behalf. I don't think it's productive to describe people as 'trolls' - we don't know why they downvoted. Just answer a couple of questions and you'll get the rep back soon enough.

Comment: @halfer Thank you, kind sir. I think downvoting without any comments is useless and can't describe it anyhow but 'trolls' and I was just a bit upset. But I got your point.

Comment: @JEYCDEE: no probs. The Stack Overflow Meta site has discussed "voting without commenting" many times, and the community's feeling is that it is perfectly acceptable. Some people like to vote on content and move on, and perhaps they assume the problem is evident. Someone's upvoted you now anyway `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the number of rows are equal to zero but I understand that you want to check if there is empty columns, the MySQL will return empty string if the column is NULL or empty in the database, so you can simply add inside the while loop a check for each column if it is empty to become equal with zero

e.g

```
if($row[1]=="") $row[1]=0;
if($row[2]=="") $row[2]=0;
if($row[3]=="") $row[3]=0;
if($row[4]=="") $row[4]=0;
if($row[5]=="") $row[5]=0;
```